# What speedup can I expect in modern PC games from switching to 3 or more CPU cores?

Tags: performance

Last I checked, almost all PC games were not noticeably faster with more than 1 or 2 cpu cores (the engines weren't very multi-threaded, apparently).

Are most games and game engines coming out now able to take advantage of more than 2 cores?

(If not, can you suggest a few that do?)

Comment: None?  A lot of games are still single threaded.  Maybe if you pick some games in particular we can give you better advice.

Comment: Would it matter? Since your more likely being bound by your GPU (depending on the screen resolution) or your hard drive, so I would worry the least about your CPU influencing the performance

Comment: @Ivo Is not 100% correct. First: HDDs only involve loading times not FPS (frame per second) performances. Second: CPU is not so marginal as people think (I tried recently on my skin). Using the same GPU as base you can have 10-30% FPS difference between various CPU (it depends also on the engine).

Comment: @tzenes: A lot of games in the past maybe. None of the bigger games released in the last two years uses less than two cores.
Even some games (Black Ops, if I remember correctly) fail to start on single core machines.

Comment: @Bora sadly even today many games are still single threaded.  While some have gotten better about it (Empire: Total War, GTAIV), others still haven't caught on: Heroes of Newerth, Modern Warfare (despite claims otherwise).  Even games which have gone beyond a single Core (Starcraft 2) max out at 2 Cores providing no extra benefit.  Its still worth prioritizing CPU speed over number of cores (and probably will be going forward given the utilization on some of these cores).

Comment: I know that Codemasters Grid and Dirt use up to 6 cores on a diminishing scale (latter cores are loaded less) if they are available. Crysis engine uses up to 3 cores effectively, Unreal engine uses 2 at the most. Of course, there is no fully efficient concurreny, because one thread for graphics, and the other for the AI, which leaves for sound and maybe network for the remaining cores, which can't really set more than 20% load on any core.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/multi-core-cpu,2280-10.html  Seems triple-core is the sweet spot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost all new engines or recent engines have been programmed with the multi-core in mind.

I am speaking about Unreal Engine 3, Source Engine, CryTek Engine, ID Tech Engine and more.

So, if you would asked this question 2 years ago, I would answered you to go with dual-core CPU and get the highest clock frequency that your budget would allow you.

But nowadays **4-core is the way**. Of course puzzle, indie or casual games will not benefit too much from multi-core. But FPS, RPG and even RTS games will do.

Choose an Intel i7 is not necessary. Intel Core i5 and AMD Phenom II X4 are great for games, bundled with a good GPU (of course).

The rule of highest as-your-budget-allow CPU clock is still valid in the 4-core CPU selection. But consider that Intel compared to AMD at the same clock frequency will win.

Comment: Note that Source Engine may have it disabled by default.  It's strangely in Settings' Video options tab as "Multicore rendering" (at least on CS:S/TF2).

Comment: @Powerlord yes, correct. And indeed I found that apply this setting for a 3-core o 4-core CPU can boost your performance of from 5% to 15%. Not bad for a CPU-based setting modification :)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at it logically: Speedup in computers is done through parallelizing only (at least significantly). If you want to publish a game that takes advantage of current computers (and that's what most games want to do) you have to make your game ready for multithreading ([see also this blog post](http://view.eecs.berkeley.edu/blog/?postid=5)).

Obviously parts like physics engine or KI can easily run each in a single process (if written like that!) which makes it easy to at least use some of the additional cores.